Mathematical reproduction and understanding of lme4 results for linear mixed model with one random intercept in R
The objective of this post is to MATHEMATICALLY recreate the results given by lmer for the following linear mixed model.
Suppose that we have $n$ test subjects. For each test subject $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$, we repeatedly measure two quantities $x$ and $y$ for $j \in \{1, \ldots, n_i\}$ times. Each such measure is denoted by $y_{ij}$ and $x_{ij}$. We carry out a linear mixed model with random intercept on each test subject :
\begin{equation*}
y_{ij} = \alpha + \beta x_{i,j} + u_i + \epsilon_{i,j}
\end{equation*}
In the equation, as usual, $u_i$'s are supposed to be independent identically distributed $N(0,\sigma_u^2)$ random variables and $\epsilon_{i,j}$ are independent identically distributed $N(0,\sigma_{\epsilon}^2)$ random variables independent to $u_i$'s. The unknown real parameters to estimate are $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\sigma_u$ and $\sigma_{\epsilon}$.
The goal is to use the known data $x_{ij}$ and $y_{ij}$ to estimate $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\sigma_u$ and $\sigma_{\epsilon}$. Since the interest has always been if $x$ has an effect on $y$, we need to carry out the hypothesis testing on whether $\beta = 0$ as well.
To do this programatically, let us use the sleepstudies data set, with $x_{ij}$ being numeric days and $y_{ij}$ being reaction. This data set happens to be balanced so let us unbalance it by deleting two rows. Here is the runnable code: (version shouldn't matter but for completeness we indicate it here lme4_1.1-34)
library(lme4)

df <- sleepstudy
df$Days <- as.numeric(sleepstudy$Days)
df$Subject <- as.factor(sleepstudy$Subject)
df <- df[-c(50, 100), ]

result <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), df)
print(summary(result))

The result is :
Warning message:
"package 'lme4' was built under R version 4.3.1"
Loading required package: Matrix

Warning message:
"package 'Matrix' was built under R version 4.3.1"
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject)
   Data: df

REML criterion at convergence: 1766.5

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.1938 -0.5299  0.0300  0.5329  4.2588 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Subject  (Intercept) 1336.0   36.55   
 Residual              961.7   31.01   
Number of obs: 178, groups:  Subject, 18

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept) 251.9298     9.6343   26.15
Days         10.2705     0.8171   12.57

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
     (Intr)
Days -0.377

By running lm(Reaction ~ Days), who does ordinary least squares, we see that, as desired, they estimate $\alpha$ and $\beta$ using ordinary least squares with $\hat{\alpha} = 251.4051$ and $\hat{\beta} = 10.4673$.
Now the problem comes. No matter what I do, I cannot find a satisfactory direct mathematical reference on the formula of the entry Std. Error in this case. And, as a consequence or as a reason, I cannot find why $\hat{\sigma_u} = 36.55$ and $\hat{\sigma_u} = 31.01$. I tried to compute several relevant square errors but none hits the values provided by lmer. What are there mathematical expressions?

The documentation of SAS PROC MIXED contains a lot of background and references -- their particular choice of technical implementation is somewhat contentious though.

This looks like a good reference. Thank you. I will read it.

I don't know how to compute this directly. The canonical reference for what lme4 is doing computationally is the Bates et al 2015 J Stat Software paper, which is accessible via vignette("lmer", package = "lme4") if you have the lme4 package installed. Everything there is expressed in terms of a general mixed model (in terms of $Z$, $\Sigma = \sigma^2 \Lambda \Lambda^\top$, etc.); you could try to derive the exact expressions for this simple case from the general case, but it might not be easy ...

As suggested by Ben Bolker, I don't think this question can be easily answered on this site. There are entire books and papers devoted to the topic. The book by Demidenko "Mixed Models: Theory and Application with R" is one that I can recommend.

Yeah I know that the general case might be difficult. Therefore, for now, I would like to do it on the really simplest special case.

Can we reproduce lme4's results manually? The short answer is: Yes, but it's extremely difficult and not always practical due to the complex challenges of mixed models. These include the optimisation algorithms, VCV estimation and numerical integration. You seem to be specifically interested in the standard errors which are derived from the inverse Fisher information matrix (the Hessian matrix of second-order partial derivatives), which itself involves numerical approximations and depends on the variance components. Even a simple case is going to be extremely difficult.

As per the comments to the question, what you are asking for is extremely difficult due to the complex challenges of mixed models. These include the optimisation algorithms, variance-covariance estimation and numerical integration. You are specifically interested in the standard errors which are derived from the inverse Fisher information matrix (the Hessian matrix of second-order partial derivatives), which itself involves numerical approximations and depends on the variance components. Even a simple case is going to be extremely difficult.  You might consider the following as a pragmatic approach:
The fixed effects are estimated using a combination of the fixed-effects design matrix ($\mathbf{X}$) and the random effects design matrix ($\mathbf{Z}$). The fixed effects estimator is:
$$
\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} = \left( \mathbf{X}^\top \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{X} \right)^{-1} \mathbf{X}^\top \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{y}
$$
where $\mathbf{V}$ is the variance-covariance matrix, which incorporates both the random intercept variance ($\sigma_u^2$) and the residual variance ($\sigma_\epsilon^2$).
Using Restricted Maximum Likelihood (REML), the likelihood function for the variance components is:
$$
L_{\text{REML}} = - \frac{1}{2} \log |\mathbf{V}| - \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{y}^\top \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{y}
$$
Maximising this with respect to $\sigma_u^2$ and $\sigma_\epsilon^2$ requires numerical optimisation, typically done using methods such as Newton's method.
The standard errors of the fixed effects are then derived from the diagonal elements of the covariance matrix of the fixed effects:
$$
\text{Var}(\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}) = \left( \mathbf{X}^\top \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{X} \right)^{-1}
$$
where $\mathbf{V}$ includes contributions from both the random effects and the residual variances.
I would point you towards the lme4pureR package which implements (some of) the functionality of lme4, but all using R, rather than compiled code. That should provide you with everything you need to do this yourself.
https://github.com/lme4/lme4pureR
[Disclaimer - I'm not sure to what extent this package has kept up with changes to lme4 itself over the years - it's been a long time since I have looked at it.]

Thank you. This is exactly the type of answer I am expecting. I shall look at the package and study it.

@温泽海  You are very welcome. I am glad that it has helped you :-)
